# Reference Request: Cardinal Division

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request

In this link, [Division of cardinals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920468/division-of-cardinals), someone asks a question about cardinal division and references a Wikipedia page about it.  The Wikipedia page does not give a reference to their statement, but I'd really like to know one.  Does anyone know specifically (preferably book and page number) where I can find this and a proof?

Comment: *The Wikipedia page does not give a reference* --- FYI, division of cardinal numbers is discussed on p. 277 of Jean Rubin's [**Set Theory for the Mathematician**](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.141528/page/n283) and in Chapter IX.6: *Quotient of cardinal numbers* (pp. 173-174) of Sierpinski's [**Cardinal and Ordinal Numbers**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Cardinal+and+Ordinal+Numbers%22+Sierpinski). Unfortunately, Sierpinski's book does not appear to be [online](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.dl-catalog-80f4c443-e772-4939-9305-45fe3beb92ec).

Comment: Thank you so much! I happen to be fortunate enough to have a hard copy of Sierpinski’s book :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the fact that cardinal multiplication is not very interesting for infinite cardinals. Namely, if $\kappa$ and $\mu$ are infinite, $\kappa \cdot \mu = \max(\kappa,\mu)$. Thus, if we're given $\lambda$ and $\kappa$ we may always solve the equation in variable $\mu$
$$ \kappa \cdot \mu = \lambda $$ if and only if $\kappa \leq \lambda$. Indeed, if $\kappa \leq \lambda$, then
$$\kappa \cdot \lambda = \max(\kappa,\lambda) = \lambda.$$ On the other hand, if $\kappa > \lambda$
$$\kappa \cdot \mu = \max(\kappa,\mu) \geq \kappa > \lambda.$$

Comment: Thank you! This also has me thinking then, what can we say about the cardinality of a quotient set? That is, if we take a set of cardinality $\lambda$ and partition it into subsets each of cardinality $\kappa$, is it true then that the resulting quotient set has cardinality $\lamda/$ divided by $\kappa$, where both $\lamba$ and $\kappa$ are infinite cardinals with $\kappa \leq \lambda$?

Comment: The cardinal $\lambda/\kappa$ is well defined (and equal to $\lambda$) only when $\kappa < \lambda$. When $\kappa = \lambda$, one has to be careful, as we may partition $\lambda$ in $\mu$ subsets (for every $\mu < \lambda$) each of cardinality $\lambda$. So, in that case, you need to calculate precisely the number of equivalence classes.

Comment: Yes of course.  Thanks again!