# penrose tilings and symmetry

Tags: reference-request, tiling

After going through the following [question on Penrose Tiling](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920323/uncountable-number-of-penrose-tiling) and reading de Bruijn's papers on the subject, I came accross Grünbaum and Shephardbook "Tilings and Patterns", p. 543, where they say that there are only two Penrose tilings with global 5-rotational symmetry. Where can one find a proof for that (that these are the only ones)?

Moreover, I then saw in Wikipedia [the following picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperiodic_tiling#mediaviewer/File:Penrose_LI_classes.svg), which somehow implies that there are more than two tilings with a  global 5-rotational symmetry... 
so what is in fact wrong here? can it be that most of the tilings in this picture are do not have a  global 5-rotational symmetry and it is only an illusion? Thank you, Thomas.

Comment: Hmm, well I know how to generate two rotationally symmetric Penrose tilings, though I'm not sure how I would show they are the only two. Start with a [sun](http://imgur.com/XOcdTun.jpg) at the origin and apply the substitution four times. This will give you a larger patch about the origin which also has a sun at the center and in the same orientation. [Here is after subbing twice](http://imgur.com/YHDfnR5) (couldn't find four). If you keep doing this, you will get an expanding patch which eventually covers the entire plane, and by construction has 5-fold symmetry. The same works for the star.

Comment: @Daniel Rust: thank you. I found this video with several subbing stages for the [sun.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbduzRBAbSc) so the wikipedia image is eventually an illusion?

Comment: An illusion? Sorry I don't follow.

Comment: @Daniel Rust: I meant, wikipedia presents several pictures of different Penrose tilings, all of them seems to have a 5-fold symmetry. But in fact only two of them have this kind of symmetry.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now, sorry. I'm not sure to be honest. The ones I defined happen to be fixed points of the substitution, but that doesn't mean there aren't 5-fold symmetric Penrose tilings which aren't fixed under the substitution. Maybe the cut and project method is a better way of looking at things.

Answer (score 1):

The list of patches in the wikipedia link are not Penrose tilings as considered by Grumbaum & Shephard, just one of them is. The former are obtained via the "cut-and-project" method, while the latter are restricted to tilings that can be obtained via inflation/deflation procedure described in the book.

In this context, the proof of the claim you ask for relies on the process of deflation: by deflating repeatedly in a 5-fold tiling you will eventually reach one of the two vertices with 5-fold symmetry (in the case of Kite and Dart tilings, either a sun or a star).